# How can I cast an object to string for use with ActiveRecord queries?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a `User`, which has a `String` `email` attribute. However, when I'm dealing with an email in my app, I find it desirable to first convert it to a (non-persisted) `Email` object, like so:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def email
    Email.new(self.read_attribute :email)
  end
end
```

`Email#to_s` and `Email#to_str` are both defined to be simply the original string (e.g., `foo@bar.com`), so it's usually pretty transparent to the client whether they're dealing with an `Email` or a `String`.

This works perfectly when assigning attributes with `ActiveRecord`:

```
> email = Email.new('foo@bar.com')
> user.email = email
```

ActiveRecord knows that the `email` attribute is a string and converts the `Email` object accordingly. Somewhat puzzlingly, it doesn't do this when querying the database:

```
> email = Email.new('foo@bar.com')
> User.find_by email: email
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: can't cast Email to string
```

Obviously, I can just call

```
> User.find_by email: email.to_s
```

But is there a way to make this cast happen automatically?

Comment: What version of Rails are you using? For Rails 4.2 and above, you can use [`attribute`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/ActiveRecord/Attributes/ClassMethods/attribute) to control typecasting behavior.

Comment: @Max He would need to define a custom `Type` for `attribute` to work since the AR is already correctly inferring the desired type from the database, but the default `Type` doesn't know how to handle `Email`. Another option would be for `Email` to inherit from `String` (or patch the case equality operator method on `String`).

Comment: @coreyward Yeah, I was thinking of a custom type that would call `to_s`. I thought it might be cleaner than overriding stuff in `ActiveModel`, but defining a custom type might be overkill just to get `to_s` to be called. Probably depends on whether this is a common pattern for the OP and it's going to need to work for additional classes.

Answer (score 5):

[This is the responsible object](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/92703a9ea5d8b96f30e0b706b801c9185ef14f0e/activemodel/lib/active_model/type/immutable_string.rb) for casting an object to a string in ActiveModel. Take a look at the [serialize](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/92703a9ea5d8b96f30e0b706b801c9185ef14f0e/activemodel/lib/active_model/type/immutable_string.rb#L8-L15) method there: it doesn't have a case for handling `Email`.

You can add one by extending the class:

```
module EmailSupport
  def serialize(value)
    case value
    when Email then value.to_s
    else super
    end
  end
end

ActiveModel::Type::ImmutableString.include(EmailSupport)

User.find_by email: Email.new('foo@example.org')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override the getter method in your model to cast it and return the string.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue a lot with Sorbet, so I added this for T::Enum

```
# typed: true
module TEnumSupport
  def serialize(value)
    case value
    when T::Enum
      value.serialize
    else
      super
    end
  end
end

ActiveModel::Type::ImmutableString.include(TEnumSupport)
```