# How can I run validations on a Rails attribute I've overridden?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

I have a `User` model with an `email` attribute. Various parts of my app conceive of an "email" differently; sometimes as a string, sometimes as a hash (`{ token: 'foo', host: 'bar.com' }`), sometimes as an object. This is bad; I want the concept of an email to be consistent wherever I use it.

So, I use an `Email` object that does what I want. I don't see any good reason to create an `Email` table; instead, I just want to create a new `Email` object corresponding to an email string whenever I need one. Therefore `User` looks like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  def email
    Email.new(read_attribute :email)
  end

  def email= email
    write_attribute :email, email.to_s
  end
end
```

However, this causes at least two issues:

1. [I can't search for a user by email without an explicit call to `to_s`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42182553/how-can-i-cast-an-object-to-string-for-use-with-activerecord-queries)
2. I can't run a uniqueness validation on the `email` column anymore. I get a `TypeError: can't cast Email to string`. (I can fix this with a custom validator.)

Questions:

1. Is there something wrong with this approach? The fact that it breaks my validation is a code smell to me.
2. Is there some way to get the existing `validates :email, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }` validation to work with these new accessor definitions?

Comment: Why is email sometimes a hash, sometimes an object and sometimes a string? This very much sounds like a recipe for a disaster to me. If you need to represent the email in different ways in much better to just add a couple of methods that return the email in the desired format.

Comment: Exactly - just treat emails as strings and parse into parts when needed. Its neither difficult nor expense.

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Attributes/ClassMethods.html this looks like what u want